# Configuring the Postgres client authorisation file for ssl

Tags: postgresql

I wish to set up my PostgreSQL server so that local access is non-SSL and non-local is always SSL. Does the configuration below achieve this?

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            CIDR-ADDRESS            METHOD

# IPv4 local & remote connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
hostssl all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this `pg_hba.conf` file will work like you desire.